# TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).val(...).prop is not a function (ionic)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've got error message like *"TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).val(...).prop is not a function"* on console log after get selected option from $scope. Please check out what's wrong from my script:

HTML Template:

```
<ion-view view-title="Doll List"> 
    <ion-content class="has-header"> 
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
          <div class="input-label">
           Product
          </div>
          <select name='options2' ng-model="item.doll" ng-options="DOLLtype as DOLLtype.name for DOLLtype in dolltype track by DOLLType.id">
          </select>
        </label>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

controller.js

```
.controller('DollCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$http', '$window', '$q', '$localStorage', '$rootScope', '$filter', 'DOLLTYPE','$timeout', function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $http, $window, $q, $localStorage, $rootScope,  $filter, DOLLTYPE, $timeout) {

 $scope.item = [];
 $scope.item = {
 id: $stateParams.id
 }; 

 $scope.dolltype = [];
 DOLLTYPE.get($scope.item.id).then(function(itemtype) { 
 $scope.dolltype.push({id:itemtype.id, name:itemtype.name})
 $scope.item.doll =  $scope.dolltype[0];
 console.log($scope.item.doll);
 })
 DOLLTYPE.all().then(function(dolltype){ 
 $scope.dolltype=dolltype;
 console.log($scope.dolltype);
 })


     }}

 ])
```

How I can fix it?

Note: DOLLTYPE is an example name for services.js for query data with cordova sqlite plugin

Comment: At first glance, it looks like parser doesn't like your track by statement for your select dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this can be triggered when you forget a semicolon.
You seem to have forgotten to put semicolons:

$scope.dolltype.push({id:itemtype.id, name:itemtype.name}) **;** <---

DOLLTYPE.get(...).then(...) **;** <---

and the DOLLTYPE.all().then(...) **;** <---

this can sometimes break when you minify